# How to draw pie chart with animation in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone

I was finding some good stuff for my app.
Actually i need to draw pie chart with animation if any one have an idea about it then please help me.

Comment: You can refer https://github.com/rajatdeep/iOS-PieChartDemo , this will be great if you use this.

Answer (score 7):

hi you can find many custom controls from www.cocoacontrols.com

here some examples like

1) https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/xypiechart

2) https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sspieprogressview

3) https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/magicpie

you can use one of them as per your requirements.

Comment: Magicpie is best from these.

Answer (score 2):

For simple pie charts, Look at this open source project [CERoundProgressView](https://github.com/Ceroce/CERoundProgressView)

You'll need to include these 4 files in your project:

- CERoundProgressView.h and .m
- CERoundProgressLayer.h and .m

See methods for displaying pie chart. You can edit animation duration and change background and track colors of pie chart as well..

Answer (score 0):

Look at this framework [CorePlot](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/)

It is a plotting framework for OS X and iOS. It provides 2D visualization of data, and is tightly integrated with Apple technologies like Core Animation, Core Data, and Cocoa Bindings.

and also you may find this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1) useful.

Comment: Do you have any other link about how to draw pie chart?

Comment: Core Plot is widely used framework for drawing graphs in iOS and it is pretty easy to customize for all kind of your graph drawing requirements.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this tutorial link...
https://github.com/tildeio/OCD3